Having strange problem changing Boolean in Laravel
So having this strange problem in laravel.
I am trying to update a boolean value in my database but i keep getting this strange error in my log:
Missing required parameter for [Route: change.stock] [URI: product/stock/{product}/{turn}] [Missing parameter: turn]
Anybody maybe knows what i am over seeing here.
My route:
Route::get('/product/stock/{product}/{turn}', [ProductController::class, 'changeStock'])->name('change.stock');

My Controller:
  <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
    use App\Http\Requests\Product\{ImageRequest,OfferRequest,DeliveryRequest,InformationsRequest};
    use App\Models\{Product,Image,Offer,Delivery,Category,Favorite};
    use Illuminate\Support\Str;
    
    class ProductController extends Controller
    {

    /**
     * Change product stock setting
     *
     * @param $switch
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     *
     */
    public function changeStock($switch): \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
    {
        try{
            $this -> setStock($switch);
            session() -> flash('success', 'You have changed your product stock setting');
        }
        catch (RequestException $e){
            session() -> flash('errormessage', $e -> getMessage());
        }
        return redirect() -> back();

    }

    /**
     * Sets the product stock status
     *
     * @param $switch
     * @throws RequestException
     */
    public function setStock($switch)
    {
        // sets stock status of product
        $this -> in_stock = $switch == 1;
        $this -> product() -> in_stock -> save();


    }

The blade file:
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm w-100 my-1 mb-4" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
                    <a href="{{ route('change.stock', 1) }}" class="btn @if 
                    ($product -> in_stock == 1)
                    btn-success btn-sm @else btn-outline-success btn-sm @endif">In Stock</a>
                    <a href="{{ route('change.stock', 0) }}" class="btn @if 
                    ($product -> in_stock == 0)
                    btn-danger btn-sm @else btn-outline-danger btn-sm @endif">Set Out of Stock</a>
                </div>


You defined your route as /product/stock/{product}/{turn} which seems to indicate it requires 2 parameters but you only provide (and use) one

thanks @apokryfos will check now and check back in.

updated controller

@Tiran100 , Call to a member function in_stock() on null means that either  product()  relationship is not properly set or the product is not found in the database, resulting in null.

It's also not clear what $this -> product() refers to I can't see it defined anywhere

Router:
Route::get('/product/stock/{product}/{turn}', [ProductController::class, 'changeStock'])->name('change.stock');

Controller:
public function changeStock(Product $product, $turn): \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
{
    try {
        $product->update(['in_stock' => $turn]);
        session()->flash('success', 'You have changed your product stock setting');
    } catch (RequestException $e) {
        session()->flash('errormessage', $e->getMessage());
    }
    
    return redirect()->back();
}


Using in blade:
{{ route('change.stock', [$product->id, 1])


you need to pass both product and turn parameters to the route
you likely have access to the $product object in your blade file

update your code like this :

<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm w-100 my-1 mb-4" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
                    <a href="{{ route('change.stock', [$product->id, 1]) }}" class="btn @if 
                    ($product -> in_stock == 1)
                    btn-success btn-sm @else btn-outline-success btn-sm @endif">In Stock</a>
                    <a href="{{ route('change.stock', [$product->id, 0]) }}" class="btn @if 
                    ($product -> in_stock == 0)
                    btn-danger btn-sm @else btn-outline-danger btn-sm @endif">Set Out of Stock</a>
                </div>


yes did this now getting another error in the log.
changed a couple things and updated the opening post.
New error is:
Call to a member function in_stock() on null

Updated the controller

Did you dd($product). If "Call to a member function in_stock() on null" is thrown, means the product is not available to the blade.
